# How can we identify if a particular url is blocked or not

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu, networking

How can we identify if my firewall is blocking url or not using shell script,

I tried

```
curl -v https://www.google.com
```

If it is open, i can see TLS handshake is completed but in the case of blocking TLS handshake is failing.

In the case of http TLS Handshake is not at all happening. I also tried netcat but no guaranteed result some websites is blocked but netcat is succeeding.

So how can we tell and which command should we include in our network test tool?

Comment: Note: TLS handshake may success but you may not get access to google. You may get a company landing page about that the site is blocked, and who to contact. (but this happens on some large corporation network: not easy and not trivial to spoof handshaking, OTOH it is allowed by standard (and required in many financial institutions). In general "blocked" is complex, and there are many layers and implementations, the only way it is to check if the result is what you expect.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up!, Since we can't take decision based on TLS Handshake so how can we check using script if particular site is open or not, as there could be so many reason behind if a website is not opening like content filtering or domain filtering etc.

Comment: I don't think there is a more reliable way than getting known content, and checking if you got what you expected.